# progress dialog inflate on top of layout onPreExecute()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, progressdialog, android-progressbar

My ProgressDialog works in the case that i show() in my oncreate method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants", true, true);  // initializes the progress dialog
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);  // on newer versions of android touching outside of the screen will close the dialog. I decided to make it only cancelable when the back button is pressed.
        setContentView(R.layout.nearby_places_list);
```

However, the dialog code wont work if i use it in an async task because its not in the on create().  The arguements  show(this, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants", true, true) arnt allowed outside of the onCreate():

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{  // this task is for populating the listview

        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //ProgressDialog.show(context, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants");
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants", true, true);  // initializes the progress dialog
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);  // on newer versions of android touching outside of the screen will close the dialog. I decided to make it only cancelable when the back button is pressed.
        }
```

This is somewhat upsetting because i wanted to show the dialog at the start of an async task but not long before that task is called.

So my question is how do make this work inside of the async task on the onPreExecute()  I don't want to have to show() until the users actually start using the async task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivitName.this, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants", true, true);
```

in `onPreExecute()`

**this** is actually the `Context` of the activity. An important thing you need to use often in future.

You can also make a `Class level variable` **Context activityContext**

and initialize it after `setContentView` in `onCreate` like this

`activityContext=this`

and then you can also use

`pd = ProgressDialog.show(activityContext, "Working", "Retreiving Neaby Restaurants", true, true);`

Comment: Perfect answer and explanation. Not something i am used to seeing on this site.  Thank you!